# Highlight cells based on another cell's value through conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I've been working on a sheet that helps me track matching numbers. To help me track easily, **I want the cells in column B ang G to be highlighted when both value matches**.

I tried different ways with conditional formatting. I think it is something doable, but I just could not figure it out after several times. It kept highlight the wrong cells.

The format in Column B and G seems to be a NUMBER.

Your help will really be appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the link to the document in case you want to have a glimpse of it. I added my 3 attempts in the sheet so you can see it. The file is editable.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I0pLi0sKWMHaDXiyCzZjc7sAOYIhp3BMkdr3AAMR3T4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

Use custom formula `=COUNTIF($B$1:$G$21,B1)>1` while highlighting only columns B and G

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: IT WORKED! do you know why my previous formulas used were not correct?

Comment: The first attempt was Google Sheets doesn't have an EQUIV function, and the other attempts was because setting a condition based off a value of a single cell only highlights values that has that same value